# is there a way to get directions in mkmapview using a built in apple API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, apple-maps

I know google maps are known to be the best maps out there, but i dont want to have to download a bunch of extra libraries and all that. I'd prefer to do something quick and simple to get a quick route from point A to B and be done with it. Is there a way to do this with built in functions/libraries? Can somebody point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

I'm not trying to get turn by turn directions or anything in my case, i just want to draw a line from start to finish. maybe give options about which routes to take. Is there a way to do it or no?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In iOS 7, you can get and display directions using `MKDirectionsRequest`.

Here's some sample code for displaying directions from the current location to another map item:

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
[request setDestination:myMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny]; // This can be limited to automobile and walking directions.
[request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES]; // Gives you several route options.
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
            [myMapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the route above roads, but below labels.
            // You can also get turn-by-turn steps, distance, advisory notices, ETA, etc by accessing various route properties.
        }
    }
}];
```

If you're new to iOS 7, you'll need to implement the `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` method for any overlay to appear. Something like:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:5.0];
        return renderer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I've discovered `MKMapItem`s aren't `NSCoder` compliant, so I've stored `MKMapItem` coordinates in Core Data. How would I turn those coordinates back into an `MKMapItem`?

Comment: @AdrianB Sorry for the late reply, but you can initialize an MKMapItem with an MKPlacemark, which can be instantiated from coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Swift version

```
        let request = MKDirectionsRequest();
        request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation();
        let locationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.724362, 100.515342), addressDictionary: nil);
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: locationPlacemark);
        request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Any;
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true;
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request);

        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
            (response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in
            print(response?.description)
            print(error?.description)
            guard let response = response else {
                //handle the error here
                return;
            }
            self.myRoute = response.routes[0]
            self.mkMapView.addOverlay(self.myRoute!.polyline)
        });
```

and its delegate

```
        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: (self.myRoute?.polyline)!)
        myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
        return myLineRenderer
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to send the address to the Apple Maps app. I just saw this done in a professional setting and that was the chosen method.

Answer (score -4):

if you want show a Alert Dialog when you tapped in a Pin make this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
[mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];

    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[PinOfProject class]])
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [view.annotation coordinate];
        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *mapitem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        self.mapItem = mapitem;

        CGPoint pin = [mapView convertCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:self.view];
        CGRect rec = CGRectMake(pin.x-13, pin.y-14,view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height);


        [self showAlertInformationForTrash:rec];

    }
}

-(void)showAlertInformationForTrash:(CGRect)rec{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show Route?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Route", @"Cancel", nil];
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showFromRect:rec inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self showRouteToAnnotation];
    }
}

-(void)showRouteToAnnotation{
    MKMapItem *myMapItem = self.mapItem;
    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    [request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
    [request setDestination:myMapItem];
    [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile]; // This can be limited to automobile and walking directions.
    [request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:NO]; // Gives you several route options.
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
                [self.mapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the route above roads, but below labels.
                for (int i = 0; i < route.steps.count; i++) {
                    MKRouteStep *step = [route.steps objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSString *newStep = step.instructions;
                    NSLog(@"%@", newStep);
                }                                                                       
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:5.0];
        return renderer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

- Oh, but note that i make a property in my .h 
  @property (strong, nonatomic)MKMapItem *mapItem;