# How to draw overlay in MKMapview?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm working on MKMapview and have a pair of static lat long values (say for eg:  80.20,13.04 & 60.55,14.05). Now i want to draw an overlay between these two points which corresponds to local roadways transport. Previously I was trying with MKPolyline & MKOverlay and I'm getting a straight horizontal line between these two points. But, I want it to correspond to the local roadways of that particular selected cities.

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772900/is-there-a-way-to-get-directions-in-mkmapview-using-a-built-in-apple-api

Comment: thanks @Anna for the reply. Will try it & post the feedback.