# Apple map back navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, apple-maps

At my ios application we show the direction of the with help of apple map.

For this direction we redirected the user the apple map.

So there is option we back to previous application with help of back navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't...

What yo can do, is present a UIViewController with MapKit inside, including directions (Or Google Maps).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're redirecting user from your app to iOS default Map app. If so then, *this isn't possible*.

For that, you've to add a `UIViewController` with (inside) a map (`MKMapView`) and code your self to show the direction (how? see this question, [is there a way to get directions in mkmapview using a built in apple API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772900/is-there-a-way-to-get-directions-in-mkmapview-using-a-built-in-apple-api)), now you'll have a back button (if you push it in navigation controller), and your user can tap on back to come back to the previous screen.

Note, you can also use the `GoogleMap` instead `MKMapView`.