# How to draw route map on Apple map between two annotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I want to achieve this following route poly line view over Apple map.[image: I want this type of route polyLine]

And want to show poly line on road, which connect from source to destination.

my code for viewcontroller header file is...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface TrackViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrAnnotation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *polyLine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *polyLineView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

my code for viewcontroller implementation file is...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    if (self.locationManager == nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

NSArray *name=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
               @"Mumbai",
               @"Chennai", nil];
self.arrAnnotation=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:name.count];

MKPointAnnotation *mappin1, *mappin2;

CLLocationCoordinate2D location[3];

mappin1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
location[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.129275,72.905273);
mappin1.coordinate=location[0];
mappin1.title=[name objectAtIndex:0];
[self.arrAnnotation addObject:mappin1];

mappin2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
location[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.063426,80.288086);
mappin2.coordinate=location[1];
mappin2.title=[name objectAtIndex:1];
[self.arrAnnotation addObject:mappin2];

[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.arrAnnotation];
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

self.polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:location count:2];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.polyLine boundingMapRect]];
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyLine];
}
```

and my out is...[image: this is my output]

Please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/166182/mapkit-tutorial-overlay-views

Comment: Thank you but want it in Objective c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way to get directions in mkmapview using a built in apple API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772900/is-there-a-way-to-get-directions-in-mkmapview-using-a-built-in-apple-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Path/Route Between two points on MapKit in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Your location array should not be filled with only two coordinates. Because adding only two coordinates will join the two points together in a straight line. So you need to add more coordinates to your location array in order to have a more accurate polyline.

Comment: how to do that please explain me...

Comment: Do you have your route coordinates?

Comment: yes i've two coordinators

Comment: @AnupamDas check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone